# Showing the very long suggestions completely on the autocomplete textview in android

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have used an `AutoCompleteTextView` in my app which shows suggestions like this:

[image]

As you can see from the image that, several suggestions are not displayed fully. There are texts left behind the visible part of the screen. What I need is that when a user types characters, it should show suggestions, and that suggestion has to be displayed completely on the screen either as a marquee, showing from one side to other side. Or display the text completely. Is this possible in `AutoCompleteTextView`? This is my code:

```
 actv1=(AutoCompleteTextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
actv1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

             @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                 String filter = s.toString().toLowerCase();
                listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
                for (String listItem : loc) {
                    if (listItem.toLowerCase().contains(filter))
                    {
                        listItems.add(listItem);

                    }

                }
                if (listItems.size() < 1){

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                        "No entries contain your search parameters",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                toast.show();

                }
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
                actv1.setAdapter(adapt);
            //  actv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                            //  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems
                                //      .size()));
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                 ArrayAdapter<String> adapt=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listItems);
                actv1.setAdapter(adapt);
            }
        });
```

and in my xml part I have done like this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:hint=" From:"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location1a">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: Did you try `android:dropDownWidth="200dp"` and 
`android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="-30dp"`

Comment: It's not working....:(

Answer (score 0):

This is custom_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"    
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

This should go in your code.

```
AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autocomplete);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter  = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.custom_item, R.id.autoCompleteItem, StringArray);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: provide some explanation to your answer!!

Comment: You can provide custom drop down to autocomplete text view. above code provide text size to drop down text. above custom_item.xml is custom layout for autocomplete text view drop down. set custom adapter. R.id.....